# Recommended Web Service Architecture Books/Sites?

Tags: web-services, design-patterns, architecture

I'm in the position where I may be creating a new web service from scratch - without much pre-existing infrastructure to have to contend with.  What resources are there that talk about the architectural aspects of deploying a web service? [Clarification: I'm not talking about an Enterprise SOA orientation here - rather setting up one family of services for the public.]

A first list of topics that I'd like to see covered are:

- SOAP vs. REST
- JSON vs. XML
- Relational Database Backed vs. SimpleDB backed vs. ?
- Scaling
- Availability
- Models for restricting access
- Models for throttling access

What would you recommend?

Comment: But maybe depends on the technology, no?

Comment: Choice of technology is another thing I wouldn't mind seeing weighed.

Comment: Given my history, I'm likely to lean toward a Linux (PHP? Perl? Ruby? Python?) and/or AWS orientation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend [Restful Web Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529260). It's weel written, very complete and vendor agnostic. Also it has a fairly good coverage of both REST (with comparison to SOAP/WS-*), HTTP scaling, resource formats (JSON, XHTML, Atom, XML), security and service modeling.

If you have any specific scaling needs, then you might also want to read [Building Scalable Web Sites](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596102356). It will teach you everything worth knowing about **etags**, **proxies**, **caching**, **edge computing** and so forth. However if you are just starting out, then the [Rest](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529260) book I mentioned earlier will properly cover most people needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to use Microsoft technology (WCF) then you could check out the Microsoft Patterns and Practices group's online library of guidance.

They have a library [located here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd441798.aspx) as part of MSDN which deals with Web Service security, Enterprise Buses (obviously not applicable to you scenario) and PAG's own Web Service Software Factory.

Their main page is [located here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/default.aspx).

Otherwise, assuming you choose WCF it might be worth checking out further reading such as [Juval Lowy's book on WCF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526997), although I fear it may cover the implementation more than the theory and design facets.

Do you know roughly what technology platform you'll be working from?